# Android Map Api V2 with menu Button

Tags: android, dictionary, menu, gps, location

Hello i just want to ask how to make a button on First Activity, so when i click Button on first activity then it will show (Launched) Second Activity which is contain Google Map v2 My Current location?

i tried using OnclickListener but the app force closed.
tried like this
display map on click of a button in android `

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btnOpen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Intent myIntent=new Intent(onclick.this,a.class);
               startActivity(myIntent);

            }
         });
    }`
```

Thank You

Comment: what's the error? look at the error in your logcat and post here. Your application is crashing probably because of some map problem.

Comment: @user2644575 welcome to SO.Change onclick.this to Activity.this and post ur logcat output here.

Comment: May you have Error in `a.java`, post locat error here for best answer

Answer (score 0):

@user2644575 welcome to so, for better help always post logcat

try `yourActivity.this` instead of `onClick.this`

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(yourActivity.this,a.class);
```

Also add SecondActivity => a inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

like

```
  <activity
            android:name=".a">
  </activity>
```

inside  `<application> tag` of `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

Your Code:

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(onclick.this,a.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Code After Change:-

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContex(),YourClassNameWhereYouWantToGo.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Note:- Be sure both activities are registered in mainfest file.

Thanks.